# JavaScript to make a dropdown box change a webpage image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning JavaScript. I want some code that will change an image on a webpage, depending on whether "image 1" or "image 2" is selected from a dropdown box. This is what I have so far.

```
$('#selectname').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === "image 1"){
    NEED HELP WITH THIS LINE
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === "image 2"){
    NEED HELP WITH THIS LINE
    }
    NEED HELP WITH SOME KIND OF ACTION HERE?
});
```

I guess that I need to get my code to change the name of the image file when the dropdown is changed - and then I need to make the image name in my html file a variable.

I'm just not sure of the syntax to do this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an image tag like this:

```
<img src="foo.png" id="imageContainer" />
```

your change listener could do this:

```
var img = $('#imageContainer');

$('#selectname').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === "image 1"){
        img.attr('src', "new_image.png");
    }
    else if ($(this).val() === "image 2"){
        img.attr('src', "another_image.png")
    }
});
```

jQuery's `.attr()` method does the heavy lifting.  [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)